# How can I get the following output,using what commands?

Tags: boxes

[image]

If there is no frame ,I just can get it .

```
\begin{verbatim}
\verb+text+
\end{verbatim}
```

but with the frame ,I don't know how to manage it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\fbox` (no need for `verbatim`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\texttt{\textbackslash verb+}\textit{text}\texttt{+}}
\end{document}
```

[image]